# how to insert multi records in db at one time with laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

This query only inserts one record to DB what should i do to insert multiple records?

```
sample_music::create(
        array(
         'artist'=>  \Input::input('artist')
        ));
```

Comment: what do you really want ? being more specific get you more answers.

Comment: @RooshanAkthar  i'll receive in Jason list of artists how can i insert them in DB .what i wrote above insert one arist (one record ) i want to insert multi-records ! u know what i mean !

Comment: use query builder for multiple insert

Answer (score 0):

assuming that you have json list as follows,

```
$str = '{
 "artist": [
            "x",
            "y",
            "z"
        ]
    }';
  $x = json_decode($str);
  $artistArr = array();
  foreach($x->artist as $artist)
  $artistArr[] = array("artist" => $artist);

 sample_music::insert($artistArr);
```

This would do

Comment: json list isn't correct ! i use postman to test this and it gives me error in the line of foreach "Trying to get property of non-object"

Comment: I assumed as the json string. I don't know your string and stuff. please provide appropriate stuffs before asking a question.

Comment: json will be like this : {"total":[{"title":"Animals","artist":"Maroon 5"},{"title":"Apologize","artist":"Timbaland"},{"title":"Back To Life","artist":"Giovanni Allevi"}]}